# Optimum way to help windows find the dll I'm linking to?

Tags: windows, dll, linker

My code is using a library which is a static/implicitly linked DLL (let's call it DLLB) but on runtime it can't find it.

This is despite locating DLLB in the same directory as the code that calls it.  (The calling code is itself a DLL, DLLA which is called from python, which is called from arcpy.  I'm not quite sure why the python finds DLLA fine but DLLA doesn't find DLLB, despite them being in the same directory).

If I put the library DLL somewhere on the system path, everything works just fine.

But what's the best approach for deployment?  Add an entry to the system path on the client machine, at install time?  Modify the system path at runtime, from python, before loading the DLL?  Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python must be specifying the full path to the DLL in the [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call.  This is recommended practice.  If you specify only a module name, there is a risk of loading the wrong DLL, possibly introducing a [binary planting vulnerability](http://www.binaryplanting.com/).

Note that although the default search path includes the directory the executable was loaded from, it does not include the directory other DLLs were loaded from.  So the behaviour you're seeing is as expected.

If you can use dynamic loading, you can look up the path to DLLA and use it to construct the path to DLLB.

To get a module handle for DLLA, call [GetModuleHandleEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  To get the full path to DLLA from the module handle, call [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Check that the last element is DLLA.dll and replace it with DLLB.dll.  You can then call LoadLibrary.

Comment: You're right, I specify the full path of DLLA in Python.  DLLB is a third party library which alas I don't think supports dynamic loading.  Which leaves the question of what's best to do - modify the system path?  Can I somehow do this just for python and it's DLL loads?

Comment: You can always dynamically load DLLs.  (Well, almost always.)  The most likely problem is that it may be too hard to change the code in DLLA to use explicit rather than implicit loading.  I think the best solution would be to explicitly load DLLB from Python *before* loading DLLA.  The implicit load will then find the right DLL because it's already in memory.  However, you could instead modify the PATH environment variable for the process using the `os.environ` mapping object.  You probably want to prepend the directory to PATH, but make sure there's nothing in there that will conflict.

Comment: Ok - I got this working with explicit linking now, thanks.  But is this really the right way to do things?  Is it somehow possible to register DLLB so that any code seeking that out can use it?

Comment: A more formal solution (overkill IMO in this case) would be to register DLLB as a shared side-by-side assembly (i.e., install it into WinSxS) and apply a manifest to DLLA.  I'm not very familiar with this approach, but see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx